# Error: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I'm working on my project now in school where I need to connect my application at Firebase. I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3. During the connection between the app and firebase, using Firebase Assistant, there's no problem. When I add the dependencies, my gradle failed with this error.

build.gradle(Module:app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.conread"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error is

> Error: Connection timed out: connect

Though I got this error, it shows in the assistant

> Dependencies are setup correctly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ideally, update Andrew Studio to 3.0...

Comment: Please share your build.gradle file and what is the error?

Comment: did u add the Google() repository in your repositories ??

Comment: I just updated my android studio to the latest version, still the error is there.

Comment: Yes, the google repository is in the m2repository.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Windows 10 firewall blocked android studio and I've got the same message.

> Error:Connection timed out: connect.

Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions:

1 Build -> Clean Project

2 Build -> Rebuild Project

3 Built -> Make Project

4 Remove your application from device and try install again

5 Mb you have some problems with actual version of yours app(try to pull actual branch). Also you can check on your emmulator, if yours app is running.

6 Try to use 1,2,3,4 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `build.gradle` file and remove `google()` in repositories. Then Try again. Your project will successfully work.